# OSX Hide application from security scanner

Tags: macos, security, vmware, vmware-fusion

I have an Mac OS Ventura 13.2

I would like to install application VMWare Fusion Player 13 with private free License for educational purpose.

On My Mackbook i have some security scanners like InfoBlox, SentinelOne and Symantec. And they see that application and make me remove it.

I Undestand that application may generate a lot of files and scanners can detect it. But seems they check only Application folder for *.app files.

How can I hide VMWare Fusion Player from scanners ?

Comment: It is just a regular app. Hide it like any other app if that is possible.

Comment: @John …and how do you propose a user "hides" an app from the system & over-zealous security apps?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to look up the manual for each of those & see how to tell it to add exceptions - if you are absolutely 100% sure the app came directly from VMWare.
If not, then perhaps believe them.
Test with [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

idk other than broad strokes what each of those is, but are you sure it's wise having three different malware scanners each potentially fighting the others? Recommended is one solution per machine, unless only one is an active scanner. Passive scanners don't fight.

Comment: Yes.. This is corporate laptop.. And ia m not sure about active scanners. Maybe only 1 is active.. 

My Goal is to hide VMWare from that scanners.

Comment: You cannot 'hide' a process from the OS, or any other app with OS-level authority. You need to talk to your IT department if it's a corporate Mac. Corporate machines are off-topic here, because we cannot help in bypassing IT rules/protocols.